# Add '?' to the end of each string in a list

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, dictionary, lambda

I am trying to add a question mark (?) to the end of each string in a list.

Currently, it is printing `['person?', 'person?', 'person?']`, but I would like it to print `['cat?', 'dog?', 'person?']`.

Could someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
def suffixQuestionMark(str_list):
    '''Returns a list of the same strings but with ? suffixed to each'''
    for s in str_list:
        str_list = map(lambda x: s + '?', str_list)
    return str_list

print (suffixQuestionMark(['cat', 'dog', 'person']))
```

Thank you!

Comment: `[s + "?" for s in ["cat", "dog", "person"]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
def suffixQuestionMark(str_list):
    return map(lambda el: el + '?', str_list)
```

Output:

```
['cat?', 'dog?', 'person?']
```

Here's what was going in your code:

```
str_list = map(lambda x: s + '?', str_list)
```

this line executes 3 times (since there are 3 words in the iterated-upon list), overwriting the `str_list` at the end of each iteration with the `['word?', 'word?', 'word?']` list, where `word` is `cat` in the first iteration, and `dog` at the second one, and finally `person`.

And that's why you end up with the `['person?', 'person?', 'person?']` list.

Answer (score 4):

Returning a list comp would be the simplest solution:

```
return [s + "?" for s in l]
```

It is also going to be more efficient than using map.

Your own code you has a lot of potential problems, why you see `person?` three times is because you use `s` in the lambda so on the last iteration when `s` is person, you map all the values to be equal to `person + ?`. Even if you changed to  `map(lambda x: x + '?', str_list)` in the loop you would then get `* len(l)` `?` added to each string. You would simply `return  map(lambda x: x + '?', str_list)` but there is no benefit using map in this instance.

You are also not using python 3 as the tag suggests, if you were you would see something like `<map object at 0x7fd27a4060f0>` returned not a list of strings.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you don't actually *have* to use the `map` function, a list comprehension is just fine here:

```
def suffix_question_mark(words):
    return [word+'?' for word in words]
```

Answer (score 0):

the `map` method already handles the iteration for you so no `for` loop is necessary:

```
items = ['first', 'second', 'third']
map(lambda item: item + '?', items) 
  => ['first?', 'second?', 'third?']
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are re-mapping your list for every string in your list.

The `map` function automatically iterates through the list and executes the lambda on it.

```
def suffixQuestionMark(str_list):
    '''Returns a list of the same strings but with ? suffixed to each'''
    return map(lambda s: s + '?', str_list)

print (suffixQuestionMark(['cat', 'dog', 'person']))
# prints ['cat?', 'dog?', 'person?']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def suffixQuestionMark(str_list):
    k = [x+"?" for x in str_list]
    print k
suffixQuestionMark(['cat', 'dog', 'person'])
```